# Info.plist indicates an iOS app, but submitting .pkg

Tags: macos, electron

I'm getting an error trying to use Application Loader to upload a packaged electron app.

I use electron-packager to package the app with the mas (Mac App Store) platform. I then zipped up the output directory. When I try I to select this .zip file with Application Loader, it gives me this error.

Comment: Look at the official guide: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide/ and make sure that you created an iTunnes Connect Record before uploading.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pack you `.app` file into a signed `.pkg`, which you can upload using `Application Loader`.

Use the following command to create a signed `.pkg` file:

```
productbuild --component YOURAPPNAME.app/ /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: YOURCOMPANYNAME (YOURTEAMID)" --product YOURAPPNAME.app/Contents/Info.plist YOURAPPNAME.pkg
```

For this to work, you'll need a Mac Installer Certificate, which you can generate from the Apple Developer website. When creating the certificate choose `Mac App Store` and then `Mac Installer Distribution`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.  The best way to request certificates (I find) is via Xcode (Preferences -> Accounts -> Manage Certificates).

Answer (score 0):

Using Application Loader 3.0 worked for me.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg

Or you can try adding this code to your info.plist.  From Unity site:

If you’re using Xcode 8.0+, you also need to add these fields to the info.plist file:

CFBundleSupportedPlatforms

```
<array>

    <string>MacOSX</string>

</array>
```

This enabled using later versions of Application Loader